# Why can't a priority queue wrap around like an ordinary queue?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

I know that in order to improve efficiency, [Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) use the [wrap around method](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/queue/array/types.html), to avoid to move everything down all the time that we delete an element.

However, I do not understand why [Priority Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) can't wrap around like ordinary Queues. In my point of view, Priority Queues have more similar behaviour to [Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) than to a Queue, how is it possible?

Comment: Priority Queue - is broad concept and can be implemented in various ways, it may be implemented as Stack and as a Queue (don't see any problems with wrap around). Often it is actually implemented as Heap. You may even implement it as Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common priority queue implementation is a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which would not benefit from wrapping around. You could create a priority queue that's implemented in a circular buffer, but performance would suffer.

It's important to remember than priority queue is an abstract data structure. It defines the operations, but not the implementation. You can implement priority queue as a binary heap, a sorted array, an unsorted array, a binary tree, a skip list, a linked list, etc. There are many different ways to implement a priority queue.

Binary heap, on the other hand, is a specific implementation of the priority queue abstract data type.

As for stack vs queue: in actuality, stacks and queues are just specializations of the priority queue. If you consider time as the priority, then what we call a queue (a FIFO data structure), is actually a priority queue in which the oldest item is the highest priority. A stack (a LIFO data structure) is a priority queue in which the newest item is the highest priority.